# Support for true 5120x1440p on M1 Pro?

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution, apple-silicon

I have an M1 Macbook Pro. I just found out it doesn't support HDMI 2.1. Because of this, it can not display 5120x1440 on my [Samsung CRG9](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/gaming/49-crg9-dual-qhd-curved-qled-gaming-monitor-lc49rg90ssnxza/) (the CRG9 supports 5120x1440). My M1 Macbook Pro will only display 3840x1080:  I've tried

- Going direct with HDMI
- And, with a [Thunderbolt 4 dock](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/docking/docking_thunderbolt-docks-(universal-cable-docks)/40b00300us) that has an HDMI port and connecting the Thunderbolt 4 dock directly to the monitor.

My question is about *other* solutions. Is there anything that will support **TRUE** 5120x1440 via a dock?

---

Definitions,

- By *"support"* I mean can be made to work with the hardware. I do not expect official support in any capacity from Apple on things they didn't extract a massive profit margin on.
- By *"true"* I mean not downscaling. In OSX terms, "native" which is weird and I'll never say that. The CRG9 can be displayed with true  3840x1080 on the M1. BetterDisplay has the ability to

  - Create a 5120x1440 "Dummy Display", this gives you the right amount of real estate.
  - Mirror the Dummy Display onto real display. The signal going out to the monitor is still 3840x1080, but everything is "smaller" (and more blurry or as OSX likes to call it "scaled").

  That is to say BetterDisplay [is not adding support for "True" 5120x1440](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay/discussions/56#discussioncomment-5293635).

Comment: If you check Mactracker, your mac does not support that resolution, how will going indirect help?

Comment: It's not really a '5k' display, it's 5k wide but only half deep. it's like 2 x 2k 27" side by side. It's not 'retina' either. It's a funny old animal, really.

Comment: @Tetsujin I removed "5k" to eliminate confusion.

Comment: OK. We seem to get these questions a lot. Macs just don't seem to like these funny ultra-wide screens. Not sure there's a definitive answer.

Comment: What is meant by “true” 5120x1440?  I’ve never heard of a resolution being a “pseudo” something-by-something. Technically, your Mac is capable of 6K resolution, but macOS doesn't play well with these super wide displays

Comment: Why not use DisplayPort instead of HDMI? Also, it would seem you should be able connect this display twice to a computer and have the computer treat the 5120x1440 display as two 2560x1440 displays. The manual refers to this as PBP (Picture by Picture) mode. The problem is macOS can not have a window across on two different displays where as Microsoft Windows can. Also, the MBP can not have two external displays without using DisplayLink.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the right-most answer to that is because I'm using HDMI Matrix switch. The reason why is because EDID passthrough HDMI doesn't require remuxing since EDID is a separate channel from the video stream. This means that computers do not know when they're disconnected and reconnected from the Matrix switch. With DisplayPort, I don't think any does EDID emulation. It's far more complex.

Comment: @Allan I've updated the question to answer that. (re: "True")

Comment: This [MacRumors thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mba-m1-with-ultrawide-49-inch-5120x1440.2271030/), with at least one participant on a CRG9, suggests that it should be plug-and-play with latest macOS... but only through DisplayPort, so your HDMI switch is the sticking point. [A Redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/comments/zv9lfy/support_m1_mac_to_samsung_neo_g9/) suggests active HDMI 2.1 adapters are currently not working on M1 in Ventura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for a solid two weeks, and investing hundreds of dollars into it, I can say **it's possible.** And, even better -- I can confirm it will work through a Thunderbolt 4 Dock. I'm using the [Lenovo Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500533-thinkpad-thunderbolt-4-workstation-dock-overview-and-service-parts). I needed two things to make this work,

- [USB-C to HDMI 2.1 adapter I used the VMM7100 from CableMatters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MSWMXT4), but you can make the [VMM6100 work too](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/dp-usb-c-thunderbolt-3-4-to-hdmi-2-1-4k-120hz-rgb4-4-4-10b-hdr-with-apple-silicon-m1-m2-now-possible.2381664/).
- [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay)

Here is the bottom line: **the HDMI on the M1 is simply crippled**. Not sure if the crippling is in hardware or software. You can read this from [author of BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay/discussions/56#discussioncomment-5313374),

> Yes, **M1 macs have severe limitations when it comes to HDMI connections and non-16:9 displays Even on 16:9 4K displays they seem to arbitrarily limit resolutions to a certain degree.** Apple seemingly tested/optimized HDMI support to suit some 4K TVs only, but not for computer monitors, that's why it is best to use DisplayPort (or USB-C which internally uses DisplayPort). An other route (if you insist on using HDMI) might be to use EDID (this is the data the display reports about itself to the computer) override to convince macOS that the display is DP instead of HDMI, that might enable 5120x1440 via the Thunderbolt dock (not the built-in HDMI though) - this is possible, because a thunderbolt dock actually uses DisplayPort (data) to communicate with the Mac and Apple Silicon Macs take what the display reports about itself (is it HDMI or DP?) in its EDID for granted whether it's a HDMI or DP (if no data is given, then it probably checks the DPCD data to figure out if behind a DP dongle or dock there is HDMI or not).

You basically have to

1. Extract the EDID of the desired monitor,
2. Modify the EDID (you can use the free [AW EDID](https://www.analogway.com/americas/products/software-tools/aw-edid-editor/) Editor), [instructions taken from here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mac-mini-4k-120hz.2267035/page-31?post=31952813#post-31952813)

   1. Ensure that DisplayPort 1.4 is enabled in EDID, if not set it
   2. Ensure that that EDID Revision 1.4 is enabled.
3. Overwrite the EDID for the monitor when plugged into the USB-C to HDMI 2.1 Adapter. For this, I used BetterDisplay.

This should enable the desired Low-PPI resolution of 5120x1440.

---

[image: Proof with OSD of 5120x1440 on OSX]

---

A huge thanks goes out to the author of BetterDisplay, waydabber, for supporting me through this process **BEFORE** I purchased BetterDisplay. Huge thanks. Inspired by [his response here.](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay/discussions/56#discussioncomment-5313374)